# How can I query a mySql table by using the value of textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm new to c# programming and I got a problem to query a mySql table, please help.

I have set up a mySQL DB and wants to query a table called 'User' by sorting the index 'passwd' in the table---the 'passwd' is a 'varchar' type.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = "server = 123.123.123.123; database=sample; uid = test;Password=test123";
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("DB Connected");

        try
        {

            command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT d,u FROM user  WHERE passwd=" + textBox2.Text;
             ...
        }
```

It looks like the last sentence

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT d,u FROM user  WHERE passwd=" + textBox2.Text;
```

doesn't work. However if I change to another query

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT d,u FROM user  WHERE  port=" + int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

then it's working fine. So it must be doing something wrong with the last sentence

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT d,u FROM user  WHERE passwd=" + textBox2.Text;
```

Comment: Just to note that your SQL (when fixed) is currently open to SQL Injection attacks because you are utilising user input directly in the SQL string.  There are a variety of elegant solutions to this issue which can easily be found via Google

Comment: Just to further note that you should never be using plain text password strings. There is a steep learning curve here, but this is a decent guide: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 0):

try this, Password is string hence you need put the text inside quote.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT d,u FROM user  WHERE passwd='" + textBox2.Text+"'";
```

Comment: It's probably better to try to supply a parameterised query solution to this problem rather than maintain the SQL Injection vulnerability the OP already has

Comment: OP can visit [Parameterised Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by another answer, the current problem in your code is that you have missed the quote characters that allow SQL to recognise your text as a `string`.

However, given that you are also vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks in your code, I've provided an alternative solution here for you:

```
command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT d,u FROM user  WHERE passwd = @passwd";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwd", textBox2.Text);
```

This achieves the same as your intention, with the added benefit that your code is using a parameterised query.

The *parameter* (`@passwd`) will be replaced with the contents of `textBox2.Text`, but it will be parsed safely so that any malicious content is not executed as raw-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT d,u FROM user  WHERE passwd=@Pwd";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pwd", textBox2.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Shyam, lt looks like you got a same solution as Martin.:)

Comment: Fraction of Seconds difference while posting the answer.